# How to copy Rcpp::DateVector to std::vector<boost::gregorian::date>

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

I want to pass data from `zoo` object into my program in C++ using `Rinside`,
but I don't know how to pass date.

Here is an example

```
 RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance


std::string cmd = "suppressMessages(library(zoo)); "
                  "z <- zoo(rnorm(10), as.Date('2000-01-01') - 0:10);"; 

R.parseEvalQ(cmd); 

 std::vector<double> v = Rcpp::as< std::vector< double > >(R.parseEval("coredata(z)"));
Rcpp::DateVector   d ( (SEXP) R.parseEval("index(z)") );

std::vector<boost::gregorian::date> dt =   //How assign d to dt ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simple converters such as this in the [RcppBDT package](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=RcppBDT):

```
template <> boost::gregorian::date as( SEXP dtsexp ) {
    Rcpp::Date dt(dtsexp);
    return boost::gregorian::date(dt.getYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDay());
}
```

which you then need to vectorise.  Alternative, maybe use integer vector (with days since epoch).

*Edit:* An there is an [entire Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-as-and-wrap-example/) devoting to this, as well as several more dealing in related topics.